Small 2D-FEM Problem: Heat Transfer from Soil to Water Pipe
I want to create a simple FEM-Model for a geothermal system from scratch.
At first I'd like to formulate the PDE and then the weak form for a simplified 2D problem. I'm not that good at maths and new to the field of PDE so I'm a bit stuck. Please excuse any rookie mistakes.
I've drawn a sketch in the picture below of what I'm imagining right now. Where q(x) is the heat flux between the Water (W) in the pipe and the Soil (S). ϕ is the flux of energy in the water on the left (x) and right (x+Δx) side of each control volume.
What is the PDE that describes this problem? Thank you!
Image: Sketch of simplified 2D Problem
